# Concatenate Fields For Join Clause

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to query a third party database that uses the concatenation of two fields as the key to another table.  I tried to use the following linq-to-sql query but got the runtime error 'LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Concat(System.String[])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.'

```
Dim result = From records In db.TableA
    Join records2 In db.TableB
    On records.FieldA + "*" + records.FieldB Equals records2.KeyField
```

What do I need to do to get this to work?

Comment: Is there anything wrong with using `+` operator?

Comment: Are `FieldA` and `FieldB` both string types?

Answer (score 0):

If you have control of the database. The easiest solution could be to add a calculated value that produces the 2 column key as a single column and join that directly with the other table, more like a proper key. This also allows you to easily persist the value and add an index for performance purposes if desired (If SQL Server, not sure about other DB's).

If you don't like the idea of altering the table in the third party database you can choose to wrap the table with a view for the program to use with the calculated column seperate from the table.